# Would a golfing tips chat room be a good idea?

Tags: discussion, chat

Lately I've been trying to get into Haskell golfing.  And its been great fun.  However I have found myself asking a lot of questions into The Nineteenth Byte ([1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38336850#38336850), [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38212032#38212032), [3](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=38141287#38141287), [4](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=37979577#37979577), [5](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37717864#37717864)).  I've also seen people asking for tips in languages I don't know (I only know python so thats a long list).  In my experience these types of golfing tips questions, don't really get any responses.  They generally get buried very quickly by the chatter that is characteristic of TNB.

I feel that it is kind of a shame that there is no real place to get good golfing tips or ask short golfing questions on the programming puzzles and *code-golf* stack exchange.  I have begun to think that it might be a good idea to create a new chat room just for tips in golfing, so that users can ask for simple tips away from the deafening noise of TNB.  Now I have enough rep to do this myself, I'm not asking for permission, but I would like to know what the community thinks about adding a room just for tips on golfing.

Comment: There's [Code Golfer's Corner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30617/code-golfers-corner), but nobody seems to use it.

Comment: @Dennis Didn't know that exists.  Perhaps that bodes poorly for my proposal.

Comment: I unfroze the room. Let's give it another chance.

Comment: I know the MATL chatroom is reasonably active (although perhaps only because MATL is under active development), so you could consider making a Haskell-specific room and see if that sticks better than the infamous Code Golfer's Corner.

Comment: @Dennis The reason might be that some of the most commonly used languages have specific chatrooms (e.g. Jelly -> Jelly, 05AB1E -> 05AB1E - Oasis, MATL -> MATL CHATL, Brachylog -> Brachylog etc.) Another reason might be that TNB drains the audience of that room.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer You're forgetting about all the practical languages. Python, e.g., is used more than twice as often as any of the languages you mention.

Comment: @Dennis Hmm, you may be right, so the second might be the reason.

Answer (score 6):

There's [Code Golfer's Corner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30617/code-golfers-corner), which is meant to discuss code golf and tips for golfing code. It seems to be pretty inactive though, so that may not be the best solution.

Comment: Why the downvotes without explanation?

Comment: Those were pretty much self-explanatory. You said what I had already said 30 minutes before, with even less details than my comment.

Comment: @Dennis Didn't see your comment at first. My apologies.

Comment: @Dennis, as a mod you should set a good example and answer in answers rather than comments :P

Comment: @PeterTaylor As a mod, well, he rightfully commented, guiding as an example, since I don't think that's actually an answer. ;)